# How to Apache SSL proxy to openerp 7 running in VM?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, odoo

I have installed openerp v7 in an ubuntu 12.04 Virtual machine from launchpad.i.e server, web, addons.

I configured SSL reverse proxy on virtual machine and my configuration for virtual host *:443 are

```
ServerName openerp.mydomain.net
ServerAdmin openerp@localhost

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/openerp/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/openerp/server.key

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyVia On

ProxyPass / http://172.16.150.14:8069/
ProxyPassReverse / http://172.16.150.14:8069/

RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" "https"

# Fix IE problem (httpapache proxy dav error 408/409)
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

</VirtualHost>
```

on host, I have configured apache reverse proxy for my subdomain in vhost_ssl.conf as

```
SSLEngine On 
SSLProxyEngine On 
ProxyRequests Off 
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all </Proxy>

ProxyPass / https://172.16.150.14/ 
ProxyPassReverse / https://172.16.150.14/         
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all 
</Location>
```

I have set `172.16.150.14`  on netrpc and xmlrcs interfaces in openerp-server.conf.
Now, when I access `https:// openerp.mydomain.net` from Girefox and chrome browser..I get `http:// openerp.mydomain.net%2C%20openerp.mydomain.net/?db=testingdb` which makes 404.

But when i access URL from IE 9, the URL https:// openerp.mydomain.net works ok .. 
secondly if i change the parameter list_db= false, then the links works as expected..

Kindly let me know what is creating bottleneck with URL redirect to `http://openerp.mydomain.net, openerp.myydomain.net/?db=testdb`  on Firefox and chrome. i am struck here doing troubleshooting with the URL to work.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to redirect http to https.

You have configured apache for https so all https requests work well.

There is no browser related issue.